# NSMutableDictionary SetObject:ForKey: is not inserting NSDictionary object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary, viewcontroller

I've been stumped with this for the last few days, I'm a bit new to objective-c.

I have up to 3 NSDictionary objects saved in the NSUserDefaults with keys "one", "two", and "three" (All contents of the dictionaries are NSStrings, so it should be ok that they're saved in the NSUserDefaults).

I am trying to load these three NSDictionaries into a NSMutableDictionary when a view apears, but for some reason they're not being added in.

```
@synthesize serverDict;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [serverDict removeAllObjects];

    NSDictionary *favs;
    NSArray *serverList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil];

    for (id server in serverList) {
        favs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:server];
        if ((favs != nil) && ([favs count] != 0)) {
            [serverDict setObject:favs forKey:server];
            NSLog(@"server:%@, objects in server:%d",server, [favs count]);
            //This outputs:
            //"server:one, objects in server:2"
            //"server:three, objects in server:2"
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"[serverDict count] = %d", [serverDict count]);
    //This outputs:
    //"[serverDict count] = 0"

     for (id key in serverDict) {

     NSLog(@"serverDict key: %@, value: %@", key, [serverDict objectForKey:key]);
     //No Output here
     }
}
```

This is in the .h file

```
@interface FavoritesViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    ...
    NSMutableDictionary *serverDict;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *serverDict;

@end
```

From the comments (NSLogs), we can see that the dictionaries exist in the NSUserDefaults, but they're not being added into serverDict.

Any help would be appreciated!! I'm still in the learning phase of objective-c...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use self.serverDict everywhere instead of serverDict except when releasing it in dealloc as it is defined as a property. Also make sure you alloc and init self.serverDict before you use it (I'm assuming you already are, but not using self.serverDict).

Comment: Oops.. I actually forgot to alloc/init the serverDict...

So for the for loop, I need to be using (id server in self.serverList)  and all of the method calls needs to be self.serverDict? (such as [self.serverDict removeAllObjects])

Comment: You've defined it as a property so serverDict is always retained and therefore exists. Using self.serverDict calls the custom getter and setter created by synthesizing serverDict. Although not visible, these release, set and retain serverDict where appropriate.

Comment: Correct. Just make sure there is a [serverDict release]; in dealloc (without the self).

Comment: Actually instead of using alloc/init I would use "dictionary" as it avoids a memory leak (your property retains it but alloc/init also retains it, whereas "dictionary" autoreleases it so only your propery retains it) - you could just call autorelease on it but it takes up more space :)

Comment: I prefer not to call getters in owning class. This just adds extra calls. It's not critical usually but in a large loops you surely don't want to call extra method instead of just accessing variable.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use the backing ivar inside the class. Using the property instead wouldn't solve this problem. @Cody

Comment: Ok I agree that in some instances you can use the backing ivar. However I prefer not to as then I always use the getter and setter and never forget to call the setter. I'm sure in some cases (such as large loops) you can shave a bit of time off, but I doubt it would be that much. Once you become competent you can do these sorts of things, but beginners should have the getter/setter use drummed into them :)

Comment: Ok, I must be a complete moron in combination with being a newbie, but how exactly do you init/alloc with self...

Comment: @nokturnal Make a new question - it doesn't matter how basic it is

Answer (score 4):

I hope you didn't forget to alloc/init serverDict somewhere?